# Python: Removing tuples from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of lists containing tuples:

```
[[(1L,)], [(2L,)], [(3L,)], [(4L,)], [(5L,)]
```

how do i edit the list so the list looks like:

```
l = [[1][2][3][4][5]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a
[[(1L,)], [(2L,)], [(3L,)], [(4L,)], [(5L,)]]
>>> a = [[x[0][0]] for x in a]
>>> a
[[1L], [2L], [3L], [4L], [5L]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have, for instance, two items in each sub-list you would need something like this

```
example_list = [[(1, 0)], [(1, 1)], [(1, 3)], [(1, 4)], [(1, 5)]]
example_list = [[x[0][0], x[0][1]] for x in example_list]
print(example_list)
```

Output: `[[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]]`

(note: this is using Python 3.8)